# Cannot Resolve symbol 'isChecked()'

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, checkbox, ischecked

I am trying to check whether the radio button is checked or not. On basis of that, I will trigger some actions. I searched and found out **"isChecked"** is the method to do so. I use that method but the **android studio** says  **Cannot Resolve symbol 'isChecked()'**.

[image]

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cream"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:checked="false"

        android:paddingLeft="26dp"
        android:text="Whipped Cream"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

final CheckBox box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cream);
     if (box.isChecked())
     {
    box.setChecked(false);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Having a similar problem now, with v

```
final CheckBox whipped_cream_variable = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream);
boolean whipped_cream_has = whipped_cream_variable.isChecked();
Log.v("MainActivity", "Has whipped cream:" + whipped_cream_has);
```

Comment: did you import whats needed? Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Till now , I have imported following 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

Comment: I just copied your code and it's working fine here. Did you try exiting your framework and opening it again? Cleaning project and rebuilding it?

Comment: It worked Dan Baruch . Thank you for it. Now I am having similar problem , Now  with "v"

Comment: Glad it's working. Not sure what other problem you are having?

Comment: I see now your new problem, did you import what's needed here as well?

Comment: I have import android.util.Log; can you suggest me what else i need to import because i am new to android.

Comment: That's all you need to import. What error are you getting exactly? cant resolve symbol of v? I'd say that's rather weird. What's your framework? Android Studio?

Comment: After trying to cut that Log.v("MainActivity", "Has whipped cream:" + whipped_cream_has); in trigger button the error gone. I searched about it and here i got the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987788/android-studios-doesnt-understand-log-function

Comment: Thanks Dan Baruch for giving me advice to solve the problem .

Comment: Sure thing, glad you got it working. Since you are rather new, I'd suggest you read some android guides to get started which can be found here https://developer.android.com/guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan Baruch solved the problem

1. try cleaning and rebuilding the project
   and
2. Try to put the statement  in the trigger button